# how to detect connection leak in jdbc using weblogic?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, connection-pooling

Is there any way to detect connection leaks in my project without going for load testing. I am using weblogic server , is there any way to detect using weblogic?

Answer (score 3):

I've never used it myself, but I think this capability has been in WebLogic since 8.x.  A series of posts [starting with this one](http://letssharejavaexperience.blogspot.com/2012/12/part-1-weblogic-connection-leak.html) appear to detail the steps.  [Here is another post](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/02/jdbc-pool-leak-using-weblogic-90.html) that shows how to use the profile connection leak functionality.

The name and location of WebLogic's Profile Connection Leak functionality will likely differ from version to version, but look first in the Connection Pool page/tab for advanced settings.